# Mongo: new is not getting the latest document

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I am having a problem where my code does not return the most up to date document, even after I have specified `new: true` and I have also tried `returnOriginal:false.` Any idea what I am doing wrong here? I am using the `$addToSet` which could be messing up something?

```
  async addFlagsToFeature(_id: number, flagDtos: FlagDto[]): Promise<FeatureResponse> {
    return this.featureModel
      .findOneAndUpdate({ new: true , $addToSet: { flags: flagDtos }})
      .then((doc) => {
        const featureDto = new FeatureDto();
        featureDto.mapFromSchema(doc);

        featureDto.flags.forEach((item) => {
          flagIds.push(new FlagDto({ featureFlagId: item.featureFlagId }));
        });
        success = new SuccessFeatureResponseDto(featureDto.id, flagIds);
        return new FeatureResponse(success, null);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.logger.error('SystemError', {}, error);
        throw new ExceptionHandler(500, 'SystemError', error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like {new: true} was set in your filter query. Try something like this:

```
return this.featureModel
  .findOneAndUpdate({_id: _id}, { $addToSet: { flags: flagDtos }}, {new : true})
  .then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc)
  }
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html